# Pgadmin4 importing CSV file Fail exit code -6

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to import a csv file into a table I created. I have set each column with data type "text" and believe to have the parameters configured correctly (delimiter, etc..)

I keep receiving the "Failed: Exit code -6" but with no explicit error message. Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3p2n.png)

Comment: i dont know pgadmin, but, in my opinion, you should try to import only one record, to understand if the problem is in the data (rows) or the columns (fields).

Comment: What happens when you select "More details..."?